# Optimal representation of an integer using two different bases

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I am wondering if anyone has ever studied "mixing two bases" together to represent an integer using the fewest number of terms in the sum.

Edit:  To clarify the bases are chosen and FIXED before you start to try and represent the integer.

As a simple example, take the bases of 4 and 9 and the integer 25.

In base 4,  25 = 121 = 1(16) + 2(4) + 1(1), so this representation requires 4 terms in the sum

In base 9, 25 = 27 = 2(9) + 7(1). so this representation requires 9 terms in the sum.

But clearly if we allow ourselves to use powers of 4 OR 9 we can do it in only two terms, 25 = 16+9

So, my question is has this idea been studied before?  Is there an efficient way to find the "optimal" representation for an arbitrary integer which requires the fewest terms(where each term is a power of one of the two bases) in the sum?

A symbolic formulation of the question I am asking, thanks to David:

Given $a,b,n \in \mathbb{N} $, how can we find the sequence's of coefficients, $\{\alpha_k\},\{\beta_k\}$ such that:

$n = \sum (\alpha_k a^k + \beta_kb^k)$ , and $\sum \alpha_k+\beta_k$ is minimized

Comment: There are a lot of definitions here that seem unclear to me. For example, in base $100$, it uses just one term. I think it's necessary to add a "cost" function or something to minimize explicitly in order to make this a constrained problem.

Comment: I mean that the bases themselves are fixed and chosen at the beginning before you do anything to the integer.  Like the 4 and 9 are important for the reason that I care about this.  I want to specifically know how to do it most efficiently for those two bases first and then hopefully extrapolate how to do it for other bases as well.

Comment: So if I were to rephrase your question: you are given $a, b, n$, and you want to find the solution to $n = \sum (\alpha_k a^k + \beta_k b^k)$ such that $\sum (\alpha_k + \beta_k)$ is minimized?

Comment: Yes that is accurate thank you.

Comment: For any fixed $n$, this is a finite pure linear integer programming problem. There is a lot of theory about these, but I must admit I don't actually know anything about it.